# Release Lock on variables used in Execute Process Task | SSIS

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, executeprocesstask

I have a package with a **Foreach Container** and **Execute Process Task** inside **ForEach Container** . On some error in Execute Process Task it redirects to **OnError** Event handler of **ForEach Container**.

I am capturing the Error from .exe using **StandardErrorvariable** property of the Task and using this in the script task which is present in **OnError** Event Handler.

The Script Task fails saying

> Error: A deadlock was detected while trying to lock variable
>   "User::ErrorExcelName, User::ErrorFolder, User::ErrorMessage,
>   User::FileName" for read access. A lock could not be acquired after 16
>   attempts and timed out.

How to fix this ?

Comment: What is causing the deadlock?

Comment: I think the Execute Process Task is not releasing the Variables and Script task is accessing it a the same time. so script task is failing after 16 attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily resolve the problem by managing the variable locking explicitly in code. (Not adding variables to `ReadOnlyVariables` and `ReadWriteVariables` properties.

```
string strFilename;
Variables lockedVariables = null;
Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForRead("FileName", ref lockedVariables);
strFilename = lockedVariables["FileName"].Value;
lockedVariables.Unlock();
```

**References**

- http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/A-deadlock-was-detected-while-trying-to-lock-variables-in-SSIS.aspx
- http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/mohitnayyar/archive/2007/09/23/update-ssis-deadlock-was-detected-while-trying-to-lock-variables-mohit-nayyar.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Hadi , but the result is Negative again. I added try catch in the script block and added the above few lines of code. When i ran i get the same old deadlock error in the catch block. How can we be sure that **Execute Process Task ** has released all its variables. As per the links you sent, variables are released and locked on used and later unlocked. So is it like **Task** is still using it or what.

Comment: Try setting the `execute process task` and `script task` `Delay validation` property = True, variable may be lock in validation phase

Comment: Nope if i add delay validation to script task ..its not even opening the script window in debug mode and its looping .. I observed one more thing ..i have few console.writeline()'s in my app but when i add any variable to the **Process** tab of **Execute Process Task** , the screen fades out and nothing displays

Comment: @Hadi I have a similar issue can you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187327/ssis-script-task-is-throwing-deadlock-error