# Execute Process Task Doesnt Display Text | SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a Foreach Container in which I have a **Execute Process Task** . I have many **Console.WriteLine()** statements in it.

The 3 images highlighted in the image can be used to get output from .exe .

I declared a variable in package to get error message from **Execute Process Task** by using **StandardErrorVariable** .

The problem is the **Screen Fades Out, it doesnt display anything on screen** , this happens not only when i use **StandardErrorVariable** but other properties highlighted in figure.

Also even though we get values into variables , the lock on them is not getting released so i am unable to use them anywhere in the package.

Also it will be helpful if you can redirect me to exact usage of all 3 variables highlighted

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when the package is run from a server catalog as well as visual studios? If you add a breakpoint, all vars will show up under the 'locals' window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I created a package and started testing in VS. I didnt get any output so didnt deploy this package to catalog or tried to run using utility or by some other ways

Comment: What process are you attempting to run? Console.Writeline() should out put to the 'output' windows in visual studios, not the process you are running with the task.

Comment: The process(.exe) has to copy fiels from X location to Y and it displays what all it copied and other information on the console screen. but if i initialize these properties with any variables , the screen fades off. In local window the variables are getting assigned and i am facing another problem which is mentioned here. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453384/release-lock-on-variables-used-in-execute-process-task-ssis )

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the control flow and the code in the script component that you are executing the Console.WriteLine() statements from.

Comment: , Here is the screenshot of control flow ( https://ibb.co/fShpyQ ) and on error of any task of the package it goes to "OnError" Event Handler and here is the screenshot ( https://ibb.co/gswA55 )